# uninitialized switchcase error in qt programming

Tags: c++, qt

This is my code for checking the laptop battery state.
I am not getting this right, because the compiler gives me an error about the switch case:

```
UPower *u = new UPower(this);

    Battery *b;
    foreach (Battery *bat, *u->batteries()) {
        b = u->batteries()->value(bat->path());
    }
    ui->batteryProg->setValue(b->percentage());

    switch( b->state() ) {
        case Battery::FullyCharged:
            ui->batteryStatus->setText( tr( "Full" ) );
            break;
        case Battery::Discharging:
            ui->batteryStatus->setText( tr( "Discharging" ) );
            break;
        case Battery::Charging:
            ui->batteryStatus->setText( tr( "Charging" ) );
            break;
        default:
            ui->batteryStatus->setText( tr( "No Battery" ) );
            break;
    }
    ui->batteryframe->setVisible(true);
```

Here's the error output by the compilation process:

```
 make: *** [Makefile:2028: corebox.o] Error 1
 make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 coreaction/coreaction.cpp: In member function 'void 
 coreaction::batteryCheck()':
 coreaction/coreaction.cpp:114:25: warning: 'b' may be used 
 uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     switch( b->state() ) {
             ~~~~~~~~^~
 ==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
 Aborting...
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: The compiler clearly explains everything. If u->batteries() is empty, than your `b` pointer is not initialized.

Comment: Please include the error in the compilation output, not just the warning you're seeing. The error seems to happen before the `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` warning is output.

Comment: You've declared a pointer without initializing it (`Battery *b`).  Afterwards you pass the uninitialized pointer through a loop over a list that as far as the compiler can tell may be empty and therefore would never run.  Afterwards, when reaching the switch statement, the compiler assumes that `Battery *b` is still uninitialized and pointing to garbage.

Answer (score 2):

This is the important part:

```
 coreaction/coreaction.cpp:114:25: warning: 'b' may be used 
 uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     switch( b->state() ) {
             ~~~~~~~~^~
```

It states that b may be used uninitialized which would be true if the loop is empty and therefore b never gets set.

```
foreach (Battery *bat, *u->batteries()) {
        b = u->batteries()->value(bat->path());
    }
```

Hope that helps.
A solution would be to test for b before the switch-statement after initializing it to nullptr.

This is the important part, there is a difference between a nullptr and an uninitialized pointer.

```
Battery* b = nullptr; // nullptr
Battery* b;           // uninitialized
```

Comment: Proposed solution is incomplete because testing uninitialized pointer against null will not work. First of all, one should write: `Battery *b = nullptr;`. Besides, the `foreach` loop is useless, as `b` pointer will point to the last battery value anyways.

Answer (score 1):

solution

```
Battery *b = nullptr;
    foreach (Battery *bat, *u->batteries()) {
        b = u->batteries()->value(bat->path());
    }
    if (!b)
        return;
```

Comment: How is this better than the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49529830/711006)?

Comment: It was posted before the other answer was edited to become complete.